# setting up customize action URL in firebase email template dynamically

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have two web application sharing one firebase (auth, db etc), it all works well, but i when users want to do a reset password, the email i can see in the Password reset template allows me to change it but i don't want to be hard specific on the url, given the password request might come from either application, is there a way to let firebase know which link to use or possibly set it from the code ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change it to a fully customized URL(like mywebapp1.com), the reason for that is that it won't be possible to check if the modified URL is a valid one.

You have 2 options:

1. You can get a custom domain like authApp.com and [follow these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/email-custom-domain) on the documentation so you can have a more personalized experience for both apps.
2. You can create dedicated emails based on the app (the URL will stay the same) using [action links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links) , this will show a nice layer of customization to your emails based on the specific web app being used.

Comment: one solution i came up with node.js was to make an ejs template for the email and in the url, i extract the actionLink i get from firebase using reg (everything after the '?') and depending on the app calling that is making the reset password request, i have the correct url and include the link i extracted (https://myapp1.com/resetpassword?mode.........(actionlink extracted)). so doing this, i can ignore the template url i set in firebase and all i am interested in is the query from the link